# lightning:input vertical alignment in table cell

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds, table, lightninginput

[image: slds table]

Hi,
I want to create a table in my lightning component. I created 2 lightning:input fields and want to change the vertical alignment to "middle" but it does not work.

I tried to do the following:

```
<td  class="slds-align-middle"><lightning:input /></td>
```

and this:

```
<td><span class="slds-align-middle"><lightning:input /></span></td>
```

and this:

```
<td Style="text-align: center;vertical-align:top;" valign="middle"><lightning:input /></td>
```

I am using slds:

```
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_col-bordered">
     <thead>...</thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr> [td in the middle of the cell] </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: It is because `lightning:input`  attribute  label  is Required , so Its creating a empty label tag in DOM

Comment: try using `<lightning:input variant="label-hidden">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<lightning:input variant="label-hidden">` to have lightning input without a space in front.